# Have two different images that are both shown the same

Tags: github, markdown, bitbucket

I'm trying to write a documentation for a code that I've put on bit bucket. The documentation involves math formulae and as far as I know, there is no way to have inline formula in bit bucket except by using some latex-to-image convertor online and inlining those images into the documentation that is written via markdown.

I used this website as my latex-to-image convertor:
http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor

I have two separate formulae with two different links and I include them in my markdown code as:

1)
[image: CBequation]
<sub>(source: [sciweavers.org](http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=X%20%5Csim%20Weibull%28%5Calpha%2C%20%5Cbeta%29%20%5CRightarrow%20f%28X%20%7C%20%5Calpha%2C%20%5Cbeta%29%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Calpha%7D%7B%5Cbeta%7D%20X%5E%7B%5Calpha%20-%201%7D%20e%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7BX%5E%5Calpha%7D%7B%5Cbeta%7D%7D&bc=White&fc=Black&im=jpg&fs=12&ff=arev&edit=0))</sub>

2. [image: BSeq]
   <sub>(source: [sciweavers.org](http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=X%20%5Csim%20Weibull%28%5Calpha%2C%20%5Clambda%29%20%5CRightarrow%20f%28X%20%7C%20%5Calpha%2C%20%5Clambda%29%20%3D%20%5Calpha%20X%5E%7B%5Calpha%20-%201%7D%20exp%5Cbig%28%5Clambda%20-%20exp%28%5Clambda%29%20X%5E%7B%5Calpha%7D%5Cbig%29&bc=White&fc=Black&im=jpg&fs=12&ff=arev&edit=0))</sub>

If you edit my question, you would see the actual link and you would see that they are different. You could easily see that one of them involves $\lambda$ while the other involves $\beta$ but for some unknown reasons both on documentation as well as here in my question, these formulae are shown the same. I spent a lot of time on it and still not figured out why they are the same.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see the problem. They look correct as far as I can tell. Can you be more specific. Also, simplify your equations to remove the not-relevant-to-this-question parts.

Comment: hey @DwayneTowell, do you also see both equations exactly the same? These are two different equations with two different links but are shown exactly the same !

Comment: Interesting! When I refresh the page initially, I see the effect you were describing. But, when I click the 'edit' link and then click 'cancel', they appear different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both images returned by http://www.sciweavers.org/, while having different URLs, appear to be the same request. The sciweavers server is returning the same image for both URLs, which could be considered a bug on their part. However, I suspect they don't care because they were not expecting to be linked to, to generate images for you.

1. [image: CBequation]
2. [image: BSeq]

Hmmm, however, editting the equation to only the difference seems to work fairly reliably. Therefore, I conclude that sciweavers' server is not doing a good job of determining when an identical request is made.